# Sql Query error asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, dataset, sqldatareader

I am using the below code to get results from my table and bind it to a gridview control .
But I get the following error:

`"System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near 'x'" at "sqlda.Fill(ds1)"`.

I am new to ASP.NET and cannot write good queries.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connStr);
con.Open();
str = "WITH x AS (SELECT *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PersonRFID ORDER BY DateStamp) FROM AISDb where action = 'IN'), y As(SELECT *, rna = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PersonRFID ORDER BY DateStamp)FROM AISDb where action='OUT') SELECT y.ID,x.ID,x.PersonName,y.PersonName,x.PersonRFID, DtATEDIFF(MINUTE, x.TimeStamp, y.TimeStamp) FROM x ,y where x.PersonRFID = y.PersonRFIDAnd x.rn=y.rnaAND  cast(x.Datestamp as date) = cast(y.Datestamp as date)Order By x.PersonName";
com = new SqlCommand(str, con);
sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
ds1 = new DataSet();
sqlda.Fill(ds1);
```

Comment: Clearly, there is an error in your SQL syntax...  Have you tried running the query directly against the database?

Comment: yes, It gives error the same error, but i don't understand that what is the mistake

Answer (score 2):

Based on my first look,(without running the query), I can see few errors.

There is typo in `datediff`.

Put the space before `AND` in the `x.PersonRFID = y.PersonRFIDAnd x.rn=y.rnaAND`

Put the space before `order` in `date)Order By`

Comment: WITH x AS  ( SELECT *,  rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PersonRFID ORDER BY DateStamp) FROM AISDb where action = 'IN' ) , y As ( SELECT *,  rna = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PersonRFID ORDER BY DateStamp) FROM AISDb where action='OUT' )  SELECT y.ID,x.ID,x.PersonName,y.PersonName,x.PersonRFID, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, x.TimeStamp, y.TimeStamp)  FROM x , y       where x.PersonRFID = y.PersonRFID And x.rn=y.rna AND  cast(x.Datestamp as date) = cast(y.Datestamp as date) Order By x.PersonName;     now i m using this query and it gives fine result when queried with database but not in c#

Comment: Debug the code, put the break point, copy the query from the Locals or Watch Window, and paste it into your Management Studio to see the difference

Comment: What is the exact error you're getting? I need more description to answer question?

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple issues with your query that are probably causing your error.  First change `DtATEDIFF` to `DATEDIFF` (this may have been a typo).

More importantly, fix your spacing.  You have fields running into each other.

See this Fiddle with both your example and the one with spacing:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/47f7e/1

You're getting that error because of this:

```
y.PersonRFIDAnd x
```

The x at the end is throwing the error.  Fix this one and the one after it (before cast) and it should work.

Comment: WITH x AS  ( SELECT *,  rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PersonRFID ORDER BY DateStamp) FROM AISDb where action = 'IN' ) , y As ( SELECT *,  rna = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PersonRFID ORDER BY DateStamp) FROM AISDb where action='OUT' )  SELECT y.ID,x.ID,x.PersonName,y.PersonName,x.PersonRFID, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, x.TimeStamp, y.TimeStamp)  FROM x , y       where x.PersonRFID = y.PersonRFID And x.rn=y.rna AND  cast(x.Datestamp as date) = cast(y.Datestamp as date) Order By x.PersonName;     now i m using this query and it gives fine result when queried with database but not in c#